# running application on client machine

Tags: windows, web-applications, installation

I have developed two applications, one ASP.NET web application (myWebAppl) and one windows application (myWinAppl).

myWebAppl Details : This application has two web pages myPage1.aspx and myPage2.aspx.
myWinAppl Details : This is a single instance windows application, which accepts some parameters.

Now from myPagep1.aspx (depending on the requirement) I want to check whether myWinAppl is installed on client machine or not

- if it is installed, I want to run myWinAppl and pass the required parameters.
- if it is not installed, the web page should prompt the user that myWinAppl is not installed on your machine, so download it from server.

How do I do this?

Shital

Answer (score 0):

You client application should have a script safe ActiveX COM component. In your page, through Javascript (so client-side), you try to instantiate that ActiveX and to execute your desired code with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your myWinAppl has Windows Installer package, you can use MSI scripting interface to determine if your app is installed using client-side javascript on web page. Also this interface can let you find out where application is installed. But custom ActiveX object is much easier to use.